# Dask how to open json with list of dicts

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dask

I'm trying to open a bunch of JSON files using `read_json` In order to get a Dataframe as follow

```
ddf.compute()

    id      owner        pet_id
0   1       "Charlie"    "pet_1"
1   2       "Charlie"    "pet_2"
3   4       "Buddy"      "pet_3"
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
_meta = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=list(["id", "owner", "pet_id"]])
    ).astype({
        "id":int, 
        "owner":"object", 
        "pet_id": "object"
    })
ddf = dd.read_json(f"mypets/*.json", meta=_meta)
ddf.compute()

*** ValueError: Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.
```

My JSON files looks like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "owner": "Charlie", 
        "pet_id": "pet_1"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "owner": "Charlie",
        "pet_id": "pet_2"
    }
]
```

As far I understand the problem is that I'm passing a list of dicts, so I'm looking for the right way to specify it the `meta=` argument

---

**PD:**

I also tried doing it in the following way

```
{
    "id": [1, 2], 
    "owner": ["Charlie", "Charlie"], 
    "pet_id": ["pet_1", "pet_2"]
}
```

But Dask is wrongly interpreting the data

```
ddf.compute()
    id          owner                pet_id
0   [1, 2] ["Charlie", "Charlie"]   ["pet_1", "pet_2"]
1   [4]    ["Buddy"]                ["pet_3"]
```

Comment: What is your `_meta`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it, it's an empty pandas Dataframe
I added it to the description of the Question. thanks for the catch up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation you want is the following:

```
dd.read_json("data.json", meta=meta, 
    blocksize=None, orient="records", 
    lines=False)
```

which can be largely gleaned from the docstring.

- meta looks OK from your code
- blocksize must be None, since you have a whole JSON object per file and cannot split the file
- orient "records" means list of objects
- lines=False means this is *not* a line-delimited JSON file, which is the more common case for Dask (you are not assuming that a newline character means a new record)

So why the error? Probably Dask split your file on some newline character, and so a partial record got parsed, which therefore did not match your given meta.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot !:D
I didn't understand the orient="records" option.  I have it clearer now